# Alguem sabe como eu faço esse efeito no background dessa div?

Tags: css

Olá, gostaria de saber como eu faço esse efeito parecido com o dessa imagem, com a sombra e os quadradinhos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe me dizer ?

Comment: você pode colocar uma imagem de um ponto que se repete varias vezes por cima

Comment: como colocar duas ? eu puxo essa com background: url(../images/minhaimagem.png) no-repeat; e a outra eu faria como ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A imagem que permite fazer esse feito quadriculado é um ponto apenas, com alguma transparência:

https://static.musiocdn.com/img/dot-overlay.png?45a8ea7a65f7

Ela é colocada por cima como *overlay*

```
<div class="dot-overlay"></div>
```

E fica por cima da imagem original em repetição com base no valor por defeito de `background-repeat` que é `repeat`. Este valor força a repetição tanto em altura como em largura dando a ideia de uma grelha.

Replicando esse efeito:

```css
.fundo {
  background-image:url(http://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2912/13981352255_fc59cfdba2_b.jpg);    
  background-size:cover;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
}

.overlay {
  background-image:url(https://static.musiocdn.com/img/dot-overlay.png?45a8ea7a65f7);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fundo">
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

A "sombra" que indica é na verdade um fundo preto com 50% de transparência por cima. Dá para incorporar isso de várias formas.

Veja um exemplo para esse efeito também:

```css
.fundo {
  background-image:url(http://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2912/13981352255_fc59cfdba2_b.jpg);    
  background-size:cover;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
}

.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url(https://static.musiocdn.com/img/dot-overlay.png?45a8ea7a65f7);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.sombra {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="fundo">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="sombra"></div>
</div>
```

Pode até utilizar um `linear-gradient` se quiser ser mais criativo.

Comment: perfeito Isac, em questão a sombra? é box-shadow mesmo ? e como eu faria ela box-shadow 0 0 0 #000;

Comment: @Bruno A sombra é um background com opacidade mesmo feito com `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

Comment: não sei como faz sombra com essa propriedade, só conheço com box-shadow, porque nos cantos é mais escuro

Comment: @Bruno Editei a resposta incluindo esse efeito que indicou

Comment: show, valeu amigo!

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa de imagem para fazer esse efeito. *(A não ser a imagem do fundo mesmo)* o resto da pra fazer basicamente com `linear-gradiente` e `repeating-linear-gradient`

Com o **CSS3** vc pode ter vários `background-image` em um elemento só! Você pode ler mais sobre isso aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

No caso do exemplo que vc mostro vamos usar 4 `backgrounds` em um só `<div>` um será a imagem de fundo, outro sera a sombra, e os outros 2 para fazer as linhas horizontal e vertical.

***A grande vantagem aqui é que vc pode usar o tamanho que quiser nos quadradinhos trabalhando com os*** `repeating-linear-gradient` ***inclusive pode trocar a cor e a opacidade facilmente***. E ainda evita problemas com requisição de imagem ou erro no caminho da imagem.

Veja os exemplos abaixo: *(com quadrados maiores e menos e com cor e transparência diferentes)*

```css
.efeito1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0px, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 4px), 
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 4px),
      linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)),
      url( http://placecage.com/800/300);

    background-position: bottom, left, top left, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.efeito2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0px, transparent 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9) 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9) 10px), 
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, transparent 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9) 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9) 10px),
      linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)),
      url( http://placecage.com/800/200);

    background-position: bottom, left, top left, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="efeito1"></div>
<br><br>
<div class="efeito2"></div>
```

**OBS:** Tirando a imagem do fundo não tem nenhuma outra. Aqui tem uns exemplos práticos de `repeating-linear-gradient` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_repeating-linear-gradient.asp

Answer (score 2):

Um exemplo:

```
<div style='background-image: url("image.jpeg"); background-size: 100% auto;'>
    <div style='background-image: url("point.jpg"); width: 100%; height: 700px;'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Observação: a imagem do ponto deve ser com fundo transparente